# iOS Dropbox API thumbnail URL

Tags: ios, url, thumbnails, dropbox-api

Is it possible to get the URL for the thumbnail of a file without downloading it using the Dropbox API in iOS? I'm currently using NSOperation to download my images from URLs to my datasource for my tableview to speed up my app.

Answer (score 0):

No, the Dropbox API doesn't currently offer a way to get links to thumbnails (as opposed to the thumbnail data itself). We're tracking this as a feature request though.

Comment: Is there any unofficial way/hack to get the url of a thumbnail?If so, how?